# How to print pandas dataframe values in a sentence

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have created a database using sqlite within python 2.7, and loaded the data into the pandas dataframe as below. What I'm trying to do is I would like to print the result as "The cities that are warmest in July are: Istanbul, Ankara, Izmir, Bursa". The code that I have written in Python is as below:

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import pandas as pd

con = lite.connect("project_warmest.db")

with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cities;")
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS weather;")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE cities (name text, region text)")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE weather (city text, warm_month text, average_high integer)")

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO cities VALUES('Istanbul', 'Marmara')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO cities VALUES('Ankara', 'Ic Anadolu')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO cities VALUES('Izmir', 'Ege')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO cities VALUES('Antalya', 'Akdeniz')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO cities VALUES('Bursa', 'Marmara')")

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO weather VALUES('Istanbul', 'July',24)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO weather VALUES('Ankara', 'July',21)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO weather VALUES('Izmir', 'July',27)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO weather VALUES('Antalya', 'August',30)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO weather VALUES('Bursa', 'July',23)")
    cur.execute("SELECT city FROM weather INNER JOIN cities ON name = city WHERE warm_month = 'July'")

    rows = cur.fetchall()
    cols = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = cols)

print "The cities that are warmest in July are: %s, " %df.iloc[0]["city"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join array of elements from `df["city"]` like

```
In [53]: print "The cities warmest in July are: %s" % ', '.join(df["city"].values)
The cities warmest in July are: Istanbul, Ankara, Izmir, Bursa
```

`', '.join(df["city"].values)` -- this will return a comma-separated string.

---

Also, you could use `pd.read_sql()` or `pd.read_sql_query` to directly read the sql results to dataframe.

```
In [54]: pd.read_sql("SELECT city FROM weather INNER JOIN cities ON name = city"
   ....:             " WHERE warm_month = 'July'", con)
Out[54]:
       city
0  Istanbul
1    Ankara
2     Izmir
3     Bursa
```